# Shifting elements in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, element, shift

I would like to make something where the strings will move up in an orderly fashion. For example:

Iteration 1:

```
Hello There
I am
Asking a question
To you
```

Iteration 2:

```
I am 
Asking a question
To you
Next String
```

How exactly would I go about this, in the least memory-intensive way? Thanks.

Comment: what code have you written so far?

Comment: I have not, but I am going to feed in new strings (e.g. 'Next String') from another array each time a message is recieved (it's a Minecraft plugin)

Comment: Shifting elements in an array require you to move all the elements. Are you stuck with an array? Because some other data structure may be better suited for the task.

Comment: why havent you tryd first? creativity problems?

Comment: @JavaNewb I don't have a clue how I would start

Comment: It sounds like you need a Queue or a Stack rather than an array.

Comment: @Dukeling I can use an array or anything similar to it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shifting Elements in an Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970857/shifting-elements-in-an-array)

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is a [circular queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).

A circular queue can be implemented as an array and a pointer to the first index. When you want to change the first element, you need only advance the index. When the index passes the end of the array, it rolls back to index 0.

With a circular queue:

- Moving up the strings does not require moving anything in the array.
- All the entries in the queue can be stored in an array, which requires less memory than a linked implementation.

Comment: Thanks, but how exactly would I go about doing that? Sorry for the simple questions, I'm just not very good with Java

Comment: You can implement a circular queue with an array and an index pointing to where the queue starts, and another index pointing to where new items will be put. Java provides this array-based queue: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html . And here's a Java implementation with an Apache license: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/CircularQueue.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you're not obliged to use an array i would suggest a queue, with it its fairly simple to implement what you wanna do.

```
Queue<String> foo = new Queue<String>();
foo.offer("Hello"); //first element is hello
foo.offer("world"); //second element is world
String s = foo.poll(); //s = hello and now the first element of the queue is world
```

Comment: Note: java.util.Queue is an interface.

Comment: Oh I was just about to ask why eclipse was returning errors, thank you!

Comment: upss sorry didnt check that! what subclass are you going to use?